# How does caffeine work as an analgesic adjuvant?

Tags: neurophysiology, psychopharmacology, pain

Caffeine [is used an adjuvant](https://www.cochrane.org/CD009281/SYMPT_caffeine-analgesic-adjuvant-acute-pain-adults) in over-the-couner pain medication, e.g. added to paracetamol [and/or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirin/paracetamol/caffeine) aspirin.

A brief look at the [Wikipedia page on caffeine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeine) doesn't indicate any analgesic effect of caffeine itself. So, what mechanism/pathway allows it to attain this adjuvant effect for pain relief?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Zhang (2001)](https://rd.springer.com/article/10.2165/00002018-200124150-00004) reports that the analgesic activity of caffeine is due to

- a blockade of peripheral pro-nociceptive actions of adenosine;
- the activation of the central noradenosine, pain-suppressing pathways;
- stimulation of the central nervous system with subsequent actions on pain perception;
- inhibition of PG (prostaglandine) E<sub>2</sub> synthesis, just like the primary mechanism of paracetamol and caffeine by blocking the COX enzyme;
- disinhibition of inhibitory adenosine actions on central cholinergic nerve terminals, leading to increased acetylcholine release and activation of cholinergic mechanisms involved in analgesia;
- lastly, caffeine-induced changes in mood may help in in pain relief.

Concerning the direct COX inhibitory action (which highly surprised me, personally) - Aspirin-like drugs act on the catalytic site of the COX enzyme. Paracetamol is believed to act at a different site, such as the peroxidation site of COX, while caffeine may block synthesis of the COX-2 protein, probably at the transcriptional level,thereby leading to enhanced COX-2 inhibition. Caffeine is a nonselective antagonist of adenosine A1 and A2 receptors. Adenosine A2a receptors induce intracellular signalling events that cause an upregulation of the COX-2 gene and the release of PGE2 in rat microglia, which is antagonized by caffeine.

[Tavares & Sakata (2012)](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/rba/v62n3/en_v62n3a11.pdf) also provide an interesting review on the analgesic effects of caffeine, without it being used in conjunction with other medications.

<sub>**References**

**-** [Tavares & Sakata, *Rev Bras Anestesiol* (2012); **62**(3): 387-401](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/rba/v62n3/en_v62n3a11.pdf)

**-** [Zhang, *Drug Safety* (2001); **24**(15): 1127–42](https://rd.springer.com/article/10.2165/00002018-200124150-00004)</sub>